# Получение SIP в приложении ios

Tags: sip

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие приложения можно использовать на IOS для того, чтобы на него переадресовывать вызовы которые поступают на купленный вирт. номер.
Коротко говоря мне нужны приложения где я смогу получит SIP номер для переадресации на него купленного виртуального.

Если я что-то не так понял - просьба объяснить как это работает. Буду премного благодарен.

Comment: Что такое «купленный вирт. номер»? Мне кажется, что поддержкой SIP должен озаботиться как раз тот, кто продал вам этот «вирт. номер»

Comment: Я пытаюсь заюзать платформу "Sonetel" для покупки вирт. номера. Для дальнейшей переадресации вызовов все сервисы требуют либо номер абонента, если ты собираешься переадресовывать посредством обычного телефонного номера, либо SIP адрес, который можно как-то получить в мобильных приложениях насколько я понял. К примеру "Zadarma" благодаря "хорошо сконструированному" сервису заботится о выдаче SIP номеров из своего мобильного приложения. Пытался нагуглить "топ приложений с возможность получения SIP" нашёл из работающих только "Zadarma" (но я хочу от неё отказаться) и 3XC который не работает.

Answer (score 0):

И так. Если кому данная тема будет интересна.
Я воспользовался связкой двух платформ:

1. Sonetel для покупки вирт. номеров
2. SipNet для получения SIP адреса, на который в последствии через мобильное приложение будет переадресовываться вызов на номера Sonetel'а.